# How to display which user not mapped course table in courseusermapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a `Course Table` which is common for all user to select their related course and saved them in `CourseUserMapping Table`. Now my requirement is i want to display all courses which user not selected in `course Table` and hide selected courses list.

```
    select c.* from Course c full outer join CourseUserMapping cum on c.CID = cum.CID 
where c.CID is NULL Or cum.CID is NULL and cum.UserID='u3'
```

the above query is not working as i expected. 
For better understand i created a picture

[image]

Comment: try to simplify your query to `select CID, CourseName from Course where CID not in (select distinct CID from CourseUserMapping)`

Comment: @KraangPrime : how to get based on `UserID`

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  Tim's solution is correct.

Comment: @KraangPrime : Tim Query is not working and your query is working for little change <kbd> select * from Course where CID not in (select distinct CID from courseusermapping where UserID='u3') </kbd>

Comment: Maybe `select CourseUserMapping.UserID. Course.CID, Course.CourseName from 
 Course
left join CourseUserMapping
    on Course.CID = CourseUserMapping.CID
where Course.CID not in (select distinct CID from CourseUserMapping)`

Answer (score 1):

Change the join to a `LEFT JOIN` and modify the `WHERE` clause:

```
select c.*
from Course c
left join CourseUserMapping cum
    on c.CID = cum.CID and
       cum.UserID = 'u3'
where cum.CID is NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` above will retain *all* courses, and then retain only those courses which did not map to any users.  This is contained within the condition `where cum.CID is NULL`.

Comment: its not working result showing empty no data display

Comment: this query working for me  ` select * from Course where CID not in (select distinct CID from courseusermapping where UserID='u3') `